# A simple query on LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

```
var q = from child in doc.Descendants("level")
        where (int)child.Attribute("id") == 55
        select (string)child.Element("Points").**Value.ToString()**;
```

I would like to get q as a type string after executing this query. Even after keeping the extra bolded line this is giving me some IEnumerable type.

Well let me put it this way. I would like to make the above query something like below one without the runtime throwing any error.

```
string q = from child in doc.Descendants("level")
           where (int)child.Attribute("id") == 55
           select (string)child.Element("Points");
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var q = (from child in doc.Descendants("level")
        where (int)child.Attribute("id") == 55
        select (string)child.Element("Points")).FirstOrDefault();
```

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method (IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)

Comment: That's kewl..thanks CD..I'm falling in love with this LINQ stuffs.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ will *always* return an enumerable result. To get it to evaluate and return one result you can use

[.First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx)

[.FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)

[.Single()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx)

[.SingleOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx)

depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The query will return IEnumerable even if the result contains single record. Try this -

```
if q.count() > 0
    var singleQ = q.First();
```

Or if you are sure that there will be atleast one record then do it like this -

```
string q = (from child in doc.Descendants("level")
           where (int)child.Attribute("id") == 55
           select (string)child.Element("Points")).First();
```

Comment: Your first one - testing `(q.count() > 0)` first - will evaluate the query twice won't it? Once to check the count then once to read the value. If you use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` then it should only evaluate it once.